# How to decode last block in LZ4

Tags: lz4

I'm trying to understand how LZ4 compresses the last block in a sequence. [According to LZ4 block format](https://github.com/lz4/lz4/blob/dev/doc/lz4_Block_format.md#end-of-block-restrictions), there are specific rules required to terminate a block.

Here is a small example:

Raw Data (a new line character is included at the end):

`abcdabcdabcd\n`

xxd dump of compressed data that is encapsulated in LZ4 frame (block starts with 0x8061 and end with 0x640a):

```
00000000: 0422 4d18 6440 a70d 0000 8061 6263 6461  ."M.d@.....abcda
00000010: 6263 6461 6263 640a 0000 0000 8f1a 578b  bcdabcd.......W.
```

According to the example above, there is only one block and there is no offset in compressed data.

How should I interpret this block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution [here](https://github.com/lz4/lz4/issues/976).

The problem arises from my misunderstanding the frame format. The block is not compressed since highest bit of the [block size field in the frame](https://github.com/lz4/lz4/blob/dev/doc/lz4_Frame_format.md#data-blocks) is set to one.